# What is this crack on my turtle’s head?

Tags: turtles, injury

I have two red eared sliders. They started fighting a while ago so I had them separated so one is in the tank while the other gets to walk around my room as he pleases and then they switch. They usually just sit under the bed. I went to check on one of them when I found this weird crack or something on his head. I don’t know what it is or if I need to take him to the vet or anything because he seems pretty normal and responsive. I know this isn’t from them fighting because this just happened and I check on them everyday, plus they haven’t had any contact in a long time[this is the full crack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRAOJ.jpg)[image]

Comment: I hope you are looking for a long term solution to separate your turtles. Red eared sliders do not life close together in nature. To give two animals the needed distances at home is nearly impossible (if your animals do not have a own room themselves). This turtles only meet to mate and make little turtles once a year. All other times they meet as rivals.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a healing wound however the whitish film nearby could be an indication of a fungal infection. Keep an eye on the area and make sure it’s free of any debris and make sure the humidity and temp are within suggested parameters. It should get smaller. If the area or whitish film gets larger you may need to take the turtle to a vet to get medication.

Comment: +1 for the humidity: The turtles need to get dry once a day, but if they has no access to water or wet places (like a wet towel) they can drying-out. This could lead to cracks in the skin.

Comment: @Allerleirauh: "turtles need to get dry once a day" - maybe they need to get wet? Or?

Comment: Thanks, the wound is actually getting smaller and more green/ blackish  (his natural color) and I will start providing more wet areas for them to chill on when they come out the tank and want to explore the room and walk around

Comment: @virolino Red eared sliders, like all of Trachemis scripta, need to get dry once a day (as rule of thumb) to get rid of fungi and bacteria at the shell and skin. Most time this is connected with the bath in the (light bulb) sun, if they have a no flat place so they can get dry under their body too. But in general they are water animals, so they need water or wet area (when they are wandering around).